# Scrapy: First delete data in export file and then write content

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a scrapy command like this

```
scrapy crawl spidername -o items.json -t json
```

If I rund this command twice the new data will be added to the end of the items.json file. However I want all the old content in items.json deleted before the new data gets saved.
How can this be achieved?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is currently impossible, sounds like a good feature to have tough.

Comment: There's an open issue on Github for this: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/547 . Comments and contributions welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use,

```
scrapy crawl spidername -t json --nolog -o - > "items.json"
```

This Way, You always get **No Append Json File**.